# Need an explanation of iptables rule

Tags: iptables

Can anyone help me understand the below iptables rule?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Comment: Answer deleted as I found I was right in spirit but horribly wrong on details when I looked up your comment on syn-flood.  Short answer, no, it would not. Further details I will leave for someone qualified.

Answer (score 3):

Radhil has been too cautious by deleting his reply, which is correct though in need of integration.

First, the literal meaning of the rule: it drops (-j DROP) all packets beginning a new connection (-m state --state NEW) which are **not** of the SYN type (!--syn) for the TCP protocol (-p tcp).

Then a few comments. In the TCP protocol, a connection is initiated by the ritual exchange of three packets, SYN (client to server) -> SYN/ACK (server to client)-> ACK (client to server). A connection **not** initiated by the SYN packet, like the one dropped by the above iptables rule, is an improper way to establish a connection which pursues different aims, as correctly pointed out by radhil.

This rule is often, and incorrectly, deemed necessary to suppress syn-flood attacks on the Web: see for instance [this Web page](https://host-palace.com/knowledgebase/article/23/tcp-syn-flood-protection---iptables/), where it is explicitly stated:

> The next pattern to reject is a syn-flood attack.
>
> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
>
> SYN-Flood-Attacks means that the attackers open a new connection, but do not state what they want (ie. SYN, ACK, whatever). They just want to take up our servers' resources. We won't accept such packages.

Of course, it makes no sense to try and defuse syn-flood attacks by *accepting* (!!!!) SYN packets for new connections. And it should be packets, not packages.

Syn-flood attacks do pose some problems which are not completely solved yet. This has led to the development of a new iptables module, called SYNPROXY, which you may find discussed [here](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2014/04/11/mitigate-tcp-syn-flood-attacks-with-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-beta/). Rate limiting is often  used, see  for instance [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-limit-linux-syn-attacks.html), but this does incur the problem mentioned in the previous reference, *i.e.* the conntrack module, which is necessary to keep track of which connections are new and which are old and in which state, works flawlessly for a limited number of connections but consumes disproportionate amounts of time when the number of connections increases (for instance, because of a SYN-flood attack). This is what is meant by a *scalability* issue.

Altogether, it is not fully clear to me that the iptables rule above serves any meaningful purpose.

Comment: Fumbled a TCP fundamental in my answer, didn't have time/energy to rewrite so it made sense again. Yours is much more thorough, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`-A INPUT` – append to the end of the "INPUT" chain

`-p tcp` – match the TCP protocol

`! --syn` – match packets without the TCP SYN flag

`-m state` – use the "state" module (deprecated; new rulesets should use "conntrack" instead)

`--state NEW` – match packets with the "NEW" state (i.e. not belonging to any established connection)

`-j DROP` – jump to the "DROP" target (which is a final target that discards the packet)

Basically TCP packets either open a new connection (and always have the SYN flag), or belong to an existing connection, or try to close an aborted connection (with the RST flag), or are garbage. So this rule tries to drop packets within the last category, which neither try to open a new connection nor belong to an existing one.

IMHO this is somewhat redundant... Maybe it's supposed to protect against various weird portscan types (as seen in nmap). Could be just paranoia too.